# Directline speech node js connection

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Hi I'm trying to enable the direct line speech channel with my chatbot developed in node js. I have done the settings by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 also webchat sample taken from https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.speech/a.direct-line-speech. I'm getting the html page with microphone and the speech is converted to text but when send that is not received in my app service endpoint. Can someone guide me what may be wrong in my implementation.

or sharing any documentations that can help me in implementing this will also be very helpful.

Comment: Have you replaced the token section in `index.js` with your own bot's token? You can use your Direct Line secret for testing, but be sure to implement a token server of some sort before deploying to production.

Comment: Yes token is added in the code but still not getting connected with app service.

Comment: What error messages do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**

1. We need to get the workspace and the bot installed into the workspace.
2. Get the bot connected into the Direct Line speech channel
3. Get the app services running and enable public access
4. Get the web app and connect it to the application services.
5. Build the static web app (HTML page) deploy it into the GitHub repository or any kind of repository. For this thread. Considered GitHub.
6. Launch the application in the browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Get the token from the created bot and use them to connect with bot created.

**Output:**

The following is the output achieved in the browser.

[image]